# Scoped configuration

Tags: java, configuration

Im currently looking to consolidate a load of configuration files. Currently for every application we have we have a set of config files for each environment we deploy to.

So for example we have a properties file for test, one for uat and one for prod. With lots of duplicated stuff.

What im looking to do is replace these with a consolidated file, using scoping and wildcards.

so, for example, I could have the following

```
*.value1=blah
uat.value1=blahblah

*.value2={value1}blah
```

So in prod:

```
value1=blah, value2=blahblah
```

In uat:

```
value1=blahblah, value2=blahblahblah
```

In test:

```
value1=blah, value2=blahblah
```

Now, I *could* roll this myself, although I'd look to leverage commons-config, but I was wondering if anyone knew of any projects out there that do this kind of thing?

Comment: Looks like Maven filtering with a default properties file will solve this: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html

Comment: If you don't need it to be in the syntax of Java properties, then Config4J will do what you want. See http://www.config4star.org. (Disclaimer: I'm the main author of that project.)